# Fire only the last event in a series of events in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a `PackingCanvas` that draws elements on the screen, which is an extension of the JavaFX `Canvas` control. I want my elements to be drawn on resize, but only when the resize is done, as redrawing the entire canvas on every resize event might be too costly in some situations.

What I have now is the following:

```
widthProperty().addListener(evt -> draw());
heightProperty().addListener(evt -> draw());
```

I have tried doing this with threads; add a small delay, see if new a new thread is created, if not; `draw()`, else abort current thread.

However, this doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me. Is there an idiom to deal with these problems?

Comment: Use [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX): "Consider a rectangle that needs to be repainted every time its width or height changes.  Using indicator and stream combinators we can reduce the number of repaints in the above example to 1."

Answer (score 0):

you can cache width & height inside draw() function.

```
void draw()
{ 
  cacheHeight = getHeight();
  cacheWidth  = getWidth();
}
```

then

```
heightProperty().addListener(evt -> {if(getHeight()!=cacheHeight) draw();});
```